# php socket not the whole data

Tags: php, sockets

I'm trying to make a site where all clients will be connected with the server and communicate with each other. What I need to do is to create sockets.

I know that through this technique, whenever a client does some action, then the other clients can immediately see it because the server will "push" the data to them (something like that. I am new to sockets anyway).

However, I don't want EVERY client to be able to see ANY data about what the other clients do, but ONLY what they have the privilege to see. (privileges are calculated through some values in a database).

**Is socket programming able to do that? If not, then I will figure out another way to make my site, maybe long-polling. (If yes, an example would be appreciated a lot)**

Comment: you should look into websocket

Comment: what's the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, socket programming in PHP is able to do that. When you write your PHP code, you can choose what to write to each socket.

There is no way to send to "all sockets at once", you will need to loop through the sockets and send data to each socket. In this loop, you are of course able to check "privileges" to make sure that you don't send anything the client should not see.

Comment: When you say "you need to loop through the sockets" you mean scanning all the ports? each socket is on one port? (im asking an extra question :) )

Comment: The ports are not important here. What I mean is socket variables. A socket is a variable in Socket programming. So you will have to loop through an array of socket variables.